# How to solve the error:ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types in the sm.models?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I tried to follow the code in this link:
https://jbhender.github.io/Stats506/F17/Projects/Poisson_Regression.html

But the error message popped up:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could 
not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

And I checked the code and found that the dummy variables did not cast as integers, it was still a factor/character. I am not sure whether the error was due to the data type or something that I don't know. Please give me some suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: As you've mentioned _dummy variables are not cast to integers_ before Poisson. Can try [astype()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) to "convert" the variables to integers, e.g. `d = d.astype(int)`

Comment: But the code in the link that I provided had this line:`dataWithDummies = dataWithDummies.applymap(np.int)`

Comment: I see what you were saying, _applymap(np.int)_ may not always work dealing with non-numeric values, so I suggested `astype(int)` alternatively

Comment: You'll get more help (or at least more people spending more than 30 seconds on this) if you give the full error, with traceback.  And the relevant code and variables.  So you know something is not numeric (float or int), but wbat?